# How to automatically remove all pinned items from Windows 10 automatically

Tags: windows-10, automation, start-menu, modern-ui

So I am currently trying to remove all of the pinned items on a windows 10 machine automatically. (Without right clicking them all and doing "Unpin from start")

I want to be able to run a command (or something along those lines) that will change the start menu from something like this...[image]

to something like this...

[image]

I have tried using the powershell command `-import-startlayout` but always get the error that the file I am trying to import "Is not a valid layout file"

I tried deleting the subkeys for:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist`

but even after a restart this didn't seem to have the desired effect.

Bonus points if you can include how to remove all of the "Most Used" as well :)

Comment: Sounds like you, should just use something like StartIsBack++, makes the layout of the start menu more familiar.  There are paid alternatives and free alternatives, this particular one, is the one I use.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply but I don't want to install third party software, I just want to remove all of the pinned start items automatically